# How to use recursive wildcards in fish shell for dotfiles and -folders?

Tags: wildcard, fish, dotfiles

The [recursive wildcards](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_wildcards) in fish are extremely useful. But if I want to use it for files or directories with a leading dot it's not working.

For example:

```
folder
├subfolder
│ └test.txt 
├.subfolder
│ └test.txt
├test.txt
└.test.txt
```

If I now run `ls -a **.txt` the output shows only the `test.txt` files which are not in a folder with a leading dot or are not dotfiles by itself. (output: `subfolder/test.txt  test.txt`)

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fish [issue #1568](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1568).

There is currently no short way to do this, the long ways are:

- Use external programs (like find)

or

- Do a more complicated glob like this one:

  ls -a **.txt .*.txt **/.*.txt

These match, in order: non-dotfiles, dotfiles in the current directory, dotfiles in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are designed to be a simple API not designed for more complex searches.

For complex searches, you can use `find` shell command.

```
find -name test.txt -print0 | xargs -0 ls -a
```

Or if you don't care about new lines in file names.

```
ls -a (find -name test.txt)
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to make complex searches. I only want working wildcards for dot-files/-folders just like the normal files and folders without a leading dot.